# Calculate the qty of items that were purchased more than once by a customer - but need to exclude the first order qty

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT        TOP 100 PERCENT soheader.custid,SOHeader.OrdNbr, SOLine.InvtID, SOLine.Descr,SOLine.QtyOrd
FROM            SOHeader INNER JOIN
                         SOLine ON SOHeader.OrdNbr = SOLine.OrdNbr
WHERE        (SOHeader.OrdDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (SOHeader.OrdDate <= GETDATE()) AND (SOHeader.CustID = '69065')
ORDER BY SOLine.InvtID, SOHeader.OrdNbr
```

here is my sample data

```
69065  WO0175279  69407  Jazzy Laces White 3
69065  WO0175393  69407  Jazzy Laces White 6
69065  WO0175393  69407  Jazzy Laces White 9
```

Now I want to know how to get the total qty of this item ordered after the first order.  I do not want to include the qty of 3 in the first record above.  I just want to include the qty of 6 in the first reorder and the qty 9 of the second reorder which equals the qty of 15.

69065 is the customer ID

WO##### is the order ID

69407 is the inventory ID

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  invtId, SUM(QtyOrd)
FROM    (
        SELECT  invtId,
                qtyOrd,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invtId ORDER BY h.ordDate, h.ordNbr) rn
        FROM    soLine l 
        JOIN    soHeader h
        ON      h.ordNbr = l.ordNbr
        WHERE   l.custId = 69065
        ) q
WHERE   rn > 1
GROUP BY
        invtId
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: @RickRosenhagen: which SQL Server version?

Comment: @RickRosenhagen: what did 2012 say?

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.2.9200.16384
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.10.9200.16688
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18051
Operating System      6.2.9200

Comment: The current compatibility level is 110.  when i execute exec sp_dbcmptlevel 'RcsApplication'

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'GUEST          ' to data type int.    what field is the value GUEST pulling from?

Comment: @RickRosenhagen: I really don't even imagine how to answer this without seeing your data and schema.

Comment: Fixed it.  WHERE   h.custId = '69065'  needed single quotes around the  custid since it is a varchar and not a int.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cl
as
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvtID ORDER BY QtyOrd) rn
from t)

select InvtID, QtyOrd, 
(select SUM(QtyOrd) from cl oo 
where o.InvtID = oo.InvtID and o.rn -1 > 0
and rn between o.rn -1 and o.rn) as 'sm'
from cl o
```

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2adef/2/0).